# Comparison between convolution filter and spectral division filter?

Tags: filters, filter-design, soft-question

Consider a signal $x=s+n$ where s is the desired signal and n is the noise we want to remove. If we know that noise is just low frequency we can remove noise by designing a low pass filter say $w$ and then recover the estimated $s_e$ by performing convolution between $s_e=x*w$. The question is can we get the estimated $s_e$  by spectral division by $$s_e=real(IFFT(\frac{FFT(x)}{1+abs(FFT(n))})$$ where $FFT(n)$ means the spectral of the noise or low frequency noise that we want to remove?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are suggesting is similar to Wiener Filtering, which is designed to optimize noise removal when signal and noise overlap spectrally. As with most of these things the devil is in the details. The math behind it isn't trivial and you will need to tackle time domain aliasing, causality, etc.

Suggested reading: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-011-introduction-to-communication-control-and-signal-processing-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_011S10_chap11.pdf